# Order mysql results by best match

Tags: mysql

Ok so imagine this mysql query...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_string RLIKE '[[:<:]]this[[:>:]]' OR
table_string RLIKE '[[:<:]]is[[:>:]]' OR 
table_string RLIKE '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' ORDER BY best_match DESC
```

and a table with the following results..

```
[id] |  [table_string]
-------------------------------
 1   |  this is a test result 
 2   |  and another one here 
 3   |  plus one more for test purposes
```

How would i make the resulting order like so?...

```
1 - **this** **is** a **test** result [BEST MATCH]
2 - plus one more for **test** purposes [SLIGHT MATCH]
3 - and another one here [NO MATCH]
```

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Edit: the ** ** are only there to emphasize the matched word, it doesnt actually have to appear like that.

Comment: just curious. i'm assuming those are regex but what does `[[:<:]]` match?

Comment: They are boundary markers showing where to start and stop matching with regex http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#leftright

Comment: so basically any column value that includes `this`, `is`, or `test`, will match?

Comment: yes, as full words, no partial word etc..

Comment: In that case, you should just use regular "LIKE" clauses or else modify your WHERE clause to use a single regex to reduce the number of table scans, as this is going to require, at minimum, an index scan on the table_string column per token unless it optimizes it away to a temp table and a join for that, as well, which you'd have to test to confirm. I'll modify my answer to show that.

Comment: The reason I used regex and boundary markers is because when using LIKE %word% it matches partial words too such as SWORD or WORDS, but with the markers it's WORD or no match.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this.
If you want to do it purely in the database, you can use a CASE clause, like so:

```sql
SELECT *, CASE
WHEN table_string LIKE '%this%' THEN 1
WHEN table_string LIKE '%is%' THEN 2
WHEN table_string LIKE '%test%' THEN 3
ELSE 4
END AS OrderRank FROM table WHERE table_string RLIKE '.*(this|is|test).*'
ORDER BY OrderRank ASC
```

This uses the conditions you specify in each "when" clause to create an extra column that you can then order based on your preference, since the database itself has no knowledge of what you mean by "best" match.

However, this is not something that is efficient in the database. You should really do it in the application, as the query plan for this sort of thing is going to involve temporary tables which will end up being pretty inefficient
and such, especially with a large dataset.

Comment: Whoops. I left off the actual CASE keyword. Fixed.

Comment: So you're saying that for efficiency i'm best just letting the mysql do the matches and use PHP to change the way it shows?

Comment: Yep. For this sort of more complex ordering, definitely. The database is efficient at figuring out _which_ data to get, and the application is capable of being much more efficient at everything else.  Plus, consider a web farm scenario. If you have more than one web server, the extra load imposed by the ordering logic can be distributed horizontally. If you do it in the database, you end up destroying the entire DB server's performance for no good gain.

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying. Thank you for the advice and info.